# ImageOverlay position by center point, set rotation and scale

Tags: leaflet

I am trying out Leaflet and I have added an image overlay according to an example I have found.

Very simple really

```
imageBounds = [[40.712216, -74.22655], [40.773941, -74.12544]];
var x = L.imageOverlay(imageUrl, imageBounds, {'zIndex':0}).addTo(mymap);
```

Now I would like to achieve the following, preferably without any plugins. I have looked into the plugins available and realised that none of them are really fit for what I need to do. I could be wrong but I thought I would try to do this without a plugin.

I have so far tried to scale and rotate the imageOverlay with css. By setting the following for example:

```
transform: rotate(45deg) !important;
```

The problem is that it does not seem to handle the origin and the image rotates around some other axis. Also when adding this the image starts to move as I zoom in and out the map.

So to summarise what I want to achieve:

- Set the position of the image overlay using lag, lng for its center position.
- Set a rotation for the image in degrees or radians
- Set the scale of the image

Would this be doable without a plugin or is there a plugin that I shoud use for this?

**EDIT 2019-02-28**:

I am now close to a solution, but I have some kind of small problem that the rotation of the image is not 100% correct. Please check the fiddle.

https://jsfiddle.net/7aq3k5se/

Comment: See https://leafletjs.com/plugins.html#tileimage-display, and in particular https://github.com/publiclab/Leaflet.DistortableImage and https://github.com/IvanSanchez/Leaflet.ImageOverlay.Rotated

Comment: @IvanSanchez thank you for the suggestion. I have actually already looked at these, but what I found out is that none of them enable me to set the center point of the image and I could also not find how to programatically set the scale and rotation. I understand you are behind Leaflet.ImageOverlay.Rotated so I guess you can give me a definite answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue. I made a mistake calculating the aspect ratio. This was not needed and it was what created the issues